# aligning left or right on bootstrap nabber

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

where in this code it says the brand will go left and the button right?

a collapse navigation bar on mobile device.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's a "nabber"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. It's here, in the Bootstrap CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right; /* <-------- */
    ...
}
```

See [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment) for more on navbar layout.